# Convert "numeric" string into some number type in Python without lose information

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, casting, floating-point

I'm creating a composite string for memorize id and sub id like this:

1.1

1.2

1.3

in this way:

```
 main_id=1 #not related to sub_id
 sub_id= 1 #or more by increment
 item = str(main_id)+"."+str(sub_id))
```

It works well when i pass to a number into a string. Keep the zeros.
Example: 1 and using number i can increment the substring without any problem.
1.1 -> 1.2 -> 1.19 -> 1.20 - not 2.0 if I use float.

The main problem  come if i want to return to a numeric type like float.

There is some way to return into a numeric type (float or other one) and keep the string content without lose anything information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to turn the string `'1.20'` into a `float` that isn't `1.2`?

Comment: why do you need it as a float?

Comment: I need to keep the zeros using numeric type. If i have '1.20' or  '1.200'i keep 1.20 or 1.200 as a number.

Comment: @RedVelvet you can't keep the zeros - 1.20 is exactly the same as 1.200

Comment: @m.wasowski because i want to insert into a database as numeric type

Comment: You cannot do that. `1.20` is mathematically equivalent to `1.2`.

Comment: @RedVelvet so you have a problem, because; 1) converting to floats always carry a risk of loosing precision, 2) you don't have one number but rather a tuple of numbers.

Comment: @m.wasowski i understood so the solution maybe is to keep separate value for the two ids and memorize ad single number in database?

Comment: Your two-part id is not a single number, so don't try to treat it like one. Either store it in your database as two numeric fields  or as a single string. It's easy enough to split the string into two numbers when you need to.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes i was thought the same thing. Now i'm sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to represent versions, in this case you should take a look at `distutils.version` module:

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'distutils.version' from 
                '/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.pyc'>
File:        /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py
Docstring:
Provides classes to represent module version numbers (one class for
each style of version numbering).  There are currently two such classes
implemented: StrictVersion and LooseVersion.

Every version number class implements the following interface:
  * the 'parse' method takes a string and parses it to some internal
    representation; if the string is an invalid version number,
    'parse' raises a ValueError exception
  * the class constructor takes an optional string argument which,
    if supplied, is passed to 'parse'
  * __str__ reconstructs the string that was passed to 'parse' (or
    an equivalent string -- ie. one that will generate an equivalent
    version number instance)
  * __repr__ generates Python code to recreate the version number instance
  * __cmp__ compares the current instance with either another instance
    of the same class or a string (which will be parsed to an instance
    of the same class, thus must follow the same rules)
```

Comment: This would make sense, but the question asks how to store these values as numbers, not strings, while retaining trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Try another way to store it

Ex. for `'1.20'`, you can store it as `float('1.02')`, `'1.200'` as `float('1.002')`

Just reverse the `sub_id` because `sub_id` don't start with zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use decimal module from python, e.g. :

```
from decimal import Decimal

[In]: Decimal("1.1")
[Out]: Decimal('1.1')

[In]: Decimal("1.10")
[Out]: Decimal('1.10')

[In]: Decimal("1.20")
[Out]: Decimal('1.20')
```